# Water level in a sinking boat is constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I came across this question in a physics worksheet:

> "A small hole is punched into the bottom of a rectangular boat, allowing water to enter the boat. As the boat sinks into the water, which of the following graphs best shows how the rate water flows through the hole varies with time? Assume that the boat remains horizontal as it sinks."

The answer given was a horizontal line, i.e. the rate is constant. The explanation on the answer key was that Archimedes Principle says the difference between the inside and outside water levels is constant, so the flow rate is constant. While I could sort of visualize this, I have never heard of Archimedes Principle used in that way. What's the proof for this (the constant difference in water level)?

Comment: Source: [F=ma 2018 A #22](https://aapt.org/physicsteam/2019/upload/Fma-2018-A-Solutions.pdf)

Comment: Your book is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buoyant force equals the density of the fluid times the local acceleration due to gravity times the displaced volume, $F_b = \rho g V$.

Suppose the boat would be floating stationary, thus under no net force, were it not for the hole allowing water through. Then, if the only forces acting on the boat are the buoyant force and gravity, we know $F_b = -F_g = mg$ where m is the mass of the boat.

The mass of the boat is not changing, neither is the density of water, nor the local acceleration due to gravity, so we have
$$mg = \rho g V$$
$$V = \frac{m}\rho$$

And therefore displaced volume is constant. If our boat is a rectangular prism that is sinking straight down, the displacement (the volume of boat that is underwater, minus the volume of boat that is full of water) is
$V = A(h-l)$
where A is the area of the boat, h is the depth relative to surface of the water of the bottom of the boat, and l is the water level in the boat.

Then "the difference between the inside and outside water levels" h-l is given by
$$h-l = \frac{V}A = \frac{m}{A\rho}$$

a constant.

---

(This only holds if our boat has a flat bottom and vertical walls and is sinking straight down. Other shapes will have constant displacement and constant flow rate, but constant displacement will only correspond to constant difference in water level under such contrived circumstances.)

Comment: This assumes that the walls of the boat have no buoyancy. If the walls have thickness, the rate of sinking will slow with time.

Comment: Why can we have V=m/p when boat is sinking? isn't the acceleration no longer 0, so how can we say mg=pgV still?

Comment: If we start with the hole already in the boat, there's no acceleration, just a continuous downward velocity (until such time as water spills over the edge of the boat - then it will accelerate as it becomes completely immersed). 

There's actually a third force on the boat provided by the flow of water through the hole, $F = -(h-l)ρgA_{hole}$, which I approximated to be 0 because the hole is stated to be small.

Comment: However, any acceleration due to this force would cause V to increase, which would cause $F_b$ to increase, like pushing on a spring, and we'd end up with $F_b = -F_g - F_{hole}$ after a little while. Thus $ρgA(h-l) = mg + (h-l)ρgA_{hole})$, combine like terms and divide, h-l still a constant.

Comment: Also I've assumed that the walls of the boat are of negligible volume relative to the size of the boat, otherwise as Ben51 pointed out the rate of sinking will slow as the boat sinks. We could of course make the hole so big that the buoyant force can't counterbalance it, but then we no longer have a slowly sinking boat, just a weird shaped bit of metal plunging straight to the bottom.

Comment: As an aside, you want $\rho$ (rho) for density, not p.

Comment: Thank you, it's a lot clearer now. I know it's rho, just didn't know how to type it